# CakePHP function is not calling from URL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cakephp, amazon-ec2

I'm implementing Aws Webservices. Configuration with aws remote host has been configured.

I'm using cake php for backend implementation.
UsersController Class is calling from url(url is mentioned below) and printing echo 'top_bar' but the add() function is not calling from url.

**This is UsersController.php class.** 
  [image]

**.htaccess**
[image]

I am using this Url:
http://18.217.215.100/cake2/app/Controller/UsersController.php

**The output is :**
[image]

When i am using this url : http://18.217.215.100/cake2/app/Controller/UsersController/add

**The output is :** 
[image]

**UsersController.class is calling from url but It print the echo "top bar" only. How could I call the add() function of the class.?**

Comment: Maybe try:  : http://18.217.215.100/users/add ?

Comment: @Salines I just tried, its not working, same error 404

Comment: You have problem with server setup (mod rewrite, ..)

Comment: @Salines can you please explain where exactly i need to change these settings?

Comment: look @ Aws Webservices docs

Comment: Have a look at https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting